# Two elements with the same class look different in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two `<hr>`s both with exactly the same class, and no other attributes on either, which look the same in Chrome etc. However in Firefox, for some reason, the one at the bottom of the page looks normal, but the one at the top is double as thick.

Any ideas? I'm also open to other suggestions if they'd work better to create a black line 2.5px high.

The issue is at every page of http://www.duncannz.com - the black line at the top looks too thick in Firefox, but the black line at the bottom is fine. Both the lines are fine in every other browser.

Comment: No idea why that's happening, but if you remove the font-class from the body. The line at the top gets thinner and the one at the bottom gets thicker. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `height: 2px;` it can't be 2.5px;

If you want to define values in decimals then try with `2.5em`. you can not use decimals with pixels. Decimals are fine on ems

Comment: Weird you can't use decimal places in px. Using `height: 2.5%;` makes the line disappear altogether though, and `2.5em` makes it super-thick.

Comment: `height: 0.1em` achieves it on FF, but makes it super-thick in Chrome... And on FF `height: 2.5em` is still too thick.

Comment: OK I think I'll just have to settle for `height: 2px` as the `em` thing isn't working. Pity though.